# How to use MintableToken, PausableToken, DetailedERC20 functions in open-zeppelin v4.4.2

Tags: solidity, erc-20, openzeppelin-contracts

I am trying to Create Token and Initial Coin Offering Contracts Using Truffle + Zeppelin Solidity. so i installed **openZeppelin** , **truffle** , **node js** , and **solidity**.

The following veresions of these softwares installed

```
Truffle: v5.4.30 
Solidity: v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node: v16.13.2
Web3.js: v1.5.3
openzeppelin:v4.4.2
```

so now i'am trying to import the following files

```
"DetailedERC20.sol";
"MintableToken.sol";
"PausableToken.sol";
```

but i did not see any of these files in my node_modules/openzepplein directory as you can see in the image attached below

Following files are present there.

[image: ERC-20 files in openzeppelin v3.0.0]

and when i read the documentation and search for these files i found these files are deprecated after the release of v3 of openZeppelin.

So what should i do know if i want to use the following function of these files
**MintableToken,
 PausableToken, 
DetailedERC20**

i am continuously searching for these files but i did not find anything.

**is there any possible solution for these files how to use their functions.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For `PausableToken` use the [ERC20Pausable.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Pausable.sol) one.
- For `MintableToken` if you use the [wizard](https://wizard.openzeppelin.com/) they suggest a combination of the `ERC20.sol` and the `Ownable.sol` the one.
- For `DetailedERC20` there is no replacement because they merged that with the `ERC20.sol` so just with using `ERC20.sol` you're using `DetailedERC20`.

If you still want to use the originals you can check [their repo on the v2.5 version](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/release-v2.5.0) and just use whatever code you need from there.

Comment: i will try to implement according to the explanation that you provided , will let you know soon. Thank you so much for answering.